# Index redirects me to a different file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Wasnt sure what to put in the title to describe what is going on, but I was looking at ways I could deny direct access to files and folders. I added a line in `.htaccess` which didnt work so I removed it.

I have access to every page on my website, but index redirects me to the page I tried to prevent direct access to. I have deleted the content of `.htaccess`, `index` and the page im been redirected to, restarted wamp and used `CTRL + F5` but nothing seem to work. No cookies are stored and no errors in inspect element.

This is my `.htaccess` file

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^http://example.com$                [NC]


#ERROR CODE -----------------------------------------------------------
ErrorDocument 400 /assets/error/400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /assets/error/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /assets/error/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /assets/error/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /assets/error/500.php

RewriteRule    ^400/?$                          /assets/error/400.php                   [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^401/?$                          /assets/error/401.php                   [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^403/?$                          /assets/error/403.php                   [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^404/?$                          /assets/error/404.php                   [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^500/?$                          /assets/error/500.php                   [NC,L]



#User Pages-------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule    ^//?$                            /index.php                  [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^signin/?$                       /signin.php                 [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^signup/?$                       /signup.php                 [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^signout/?$                      /signout.php                [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^forgot-password/?$              /forgot-password.php        [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^credits/?$                      /credits.php                [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^leaderboard/?$                  /leaderboard.php            [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^updates/?$                      /updates.php                [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^live/?$                         /live.php                   [NC,L]


#Misc--------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule    ^misc/?$                         /misc.php                   [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^maintenance/?$                  /maintenance.php            [NC,L]


#Maintenance-------------------------------------------------------
# files to load
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/css/main.css$
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/css/special.css$
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php$
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.htaccess$

# here filter the developer's IP/
# RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^212.251.187.11

# redirect page (maintenance page)
# RewriteRule $ /maintenance [R=302,L]
```

**Edit**

The problem seem to be occurring when I use `example.com` or `example.com/`, but not when using `example.com/index.php`.
There is only 1 `.htaccess` file been used and I've not made any changes to the apache files (atleast not my self), Im trying to find the `.htaccess` snippets I tried right before this started happening

Comment: @Hallur oops sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I transfered my root folder to a different pc and everything works. I'm not sure what went wrong but I was not able to fix the problem. I'm reinstalling wamp to see if that solves the problem. I belive this is the code that I used before index stopped working `Redirect 301 /old/file.html http://yourdomain.com/new/file.html` I never replaced any of it with the index but with a `404` page and the page I was been redirected to.

The snippet was taken from:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/21-very-useful-htaccess-tips-tricks/